Was the evidence about the doctor's parents' deaths fabricated or a lucky coincidence?
In Spy Game (2001), as part of getting the doctor to kill their target in Beirut, Muir presents him with some photos of his dead parents and says:

We have a reason to believe your parents' deaths were not accidental.

Did they fabricate the evidence or just got lucky with this episode in the doctor's life? I don't recall the doctor being targeted from the get-go; instead, they were trying to 'make it look like an accident.'
Also, it's important to note that Muir didn't know about the doctor until he got to Beirut (i.e., him gathering intel on the doctor before arriving is out of the question). So Bishop signaled for Muir to arrive without having a clear picture on how to motivate the doctor, it seems.
When talking about the whole thing during the recorded CIA meeting, Muir is ambiguous in saying the doctor's parents 'died' without implying if they were really killed.

We don't know if his parents were actually murdered.
It seems to me they researched the doctor and picked an incident in his life they could exploit to get him to co-operate.
Whether his parents were actually murdered is irrelevant to the plan.... it's just a pressure point.
